# Goutte Scraper Parse through Page Object

Tags: symfony, web-scraping, web-crawler, guzzle, goutte

it's been kind of a learning experience for me, but using Symfony and Goutte. I've been able to login to a secure website then return a page.

```
echo $crawler->html();
```

What I want to do now is parse through the object `$crawler`. What confuses me is Goutte doesn't seem to show much about how to do this. I think a lot of people have used Guzzle along with Goutte, but I can't do a `use Guzzle\Client;` statement along with `use Goutte\Client;`.

All I want to do is parse through the `$crawler` object to find certain things in the html source code. (Note: this specific page does not use id's or classes, so I can't do `filter('#stuff')` or `filter('.stuff')`.)

Can someone help explain to me how to use Goutte to parse through the object I've gotten?

(edit: I wanted to specify, I'm trying to perhaps just search for a string or something. Can I convert the `$crawler` object to plain text source code then just do a `preg_match` or something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $crawler is an instance of the [Symfony DomCrawler Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html); which is actually set of [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) objects.

The crawler provides quite a bit of functionality for [filtering individual nodes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-filtering) by using XPath queries

```
$crawler = $crawler->filterXPath('descendant-or-self::body/p');
```

or by using CSS Selectors.

```
$crawler = $crawler->filter('body > p');
```

By using either, it is possible to filter your document using HTML entities rather than by attributes.  More information on CSS Selectors can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (it was the first link from a Google search).

The ability to output the inner HTML of a crawler object was added in 2.3 and can be completed by:

The DomCrawler::html() method was added in Symfony 2.3 and it will "return the first node of the list as HTML".

```
$html = $crawler->html();
```

It should be noted that when you perform a filter, a new crawler object is returned with a list of [DOMElements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) which can lead to some unexpected results (at least that's what I have experienced).

Edit: In response to your comment, it is entirely possible to filter based off of the new criteria (reference the comment below).

You use a CSS Selector like:

> [attribute=value]

So your code would look like:

```
$crawler = $crawler->filter('a[href=' . $value . ']');
```

Accessing node values can be as simple as using the [DOMCrawler Supplied Functions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values) or by accessing the underlying DOMNode / NodeList / DOMElement elements.

Behind the scenes the [DomCrawler Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) makes use of the [CSS Selector Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! let's say there's an `<a href="www.stuff.com/junkServlet?id=12345">` and what I need to search for is the string "www.stuff.com/junkServlet?id=". That changes the picture entirely, you can't use filer or anything. And what if there's a specific `<p>` tag I need? Once I find all of them, how could i find the `href=" "` that I need?

Comment: modified response above to respond to your new questions.

Comment: Thank for that it helps a lot! Lastly, are wildcards allowed? For example, let's say the link has a BUNCH of junk it it: `<a onclick="window.open('http://thing.place.com/r.htm?e=842697&s=1&k=A2CF3582ECD50B5F218FE39F36C9A80C','thingURL','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=800');return false;" href="#">Some URL</a>` and all I can supply for a search term is this part `http://thing.place.com/r.htm?e=842697&s`. Are wildcards allowed? so that I can search the entire `onclick` with only a portion of a string that may be in it?

Comment: The CSS Selector link above shows how you can use wildcards like:"~", "|", "$", "*", "^" .  You use it like [attribute{wildcard}=value].  If that doesn't work, you might want to look at DomCrawler::reduce().  Ultimately, once you have the value, you can filter it or do whatever you'd like with it.